# How to add 1 hour from current date

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I got problem when user click NOW..Time must display to add 1 hour from current time. I'm using date picker when load it display current time just problem to add 1 hour not working. This is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-lvvsf1) demo.

HTML

```
<ion-list  lines="none" class="ion-list-time">
        <ion-radio-group mode="md"  value="NOW">
          <ion-item  >
            <!-- <ion-col class="d-flex"> -->
            <ion-label for="q1" class="as-center">Now</ion-label>
            <ion-radio  slot="start" (ionFocus)="radioFocus()" value="NOW" id="q1"></ion-radio>
          <!-- </ion-col> -->
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <!-- <ion-col class="d-flex"> -->
            <ion-label for="q2" class="as-center">Later</ion-label>
            <ion-radio slot="start" (ionFocus)="radioFocus()" value="LATER" id="q2"></ion-radio>
          <!-- </ion-col> -->
            <ion-col class="d-flex" *ngIf="isTimeShow">
            <ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm A" [(ngModel)]="TakeAwayTime" placeholder="time"></ion-datetime>
          </ion-col>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label for="q3">Time</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm A" [(ngModel)]="TakeAwayTime" id="q3"></ion-datetime>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-radio-group>
      </ion-list>
```

Component

```
TakeAwayTime: String = new Date().toISOString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this, hope will helpfull

````
 radioFocus() {
    var dt = new Date();
    console.log(dt)
     // adding 60 minute in current time and assigning it again to ```this.TakeAwayTime```
    const newdate = dt.setMinutes( dt.getMinutes() + 60 );
    this.TakeAwayTime = new Date( newdate).toISOString();
    // document.write( this.TakeAwayTime.toString());
    // document.write( newdate);
  }
  // calling this function on radio now button focus
  now() {
    this.TakeAwayTime = new Date().toISOString();
  }



<ion-app>
   <ion-list  lines="none" class="ion-list-time">
        <ion-radio-group mode="md"  value="NOW">
          <ion-item  >
            <!-- <ion-col class="d-flex"> -->
            <ion-label for="q1" class="as-center">Now</ion-label>
            <ion-radio  slot="start" (ionFocus)="now()" value="NOW" id="q1"></ion-radio>
          <!-- </ion-col> -->
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <!-- <ion-col class="d-flex"> -->
            <ion-label for="q2" class="as-center">Later</ion-label>
            <ion-radio slot="start" (ionFocus)="radioFocus()" value="LATER" id="q2"></ion-radio>
          <!-- </ion-col> -->
            <ion-col class="d-flex" *ngIf="isTimeShow">
            <ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm A" [(ngModel)]="TakeAwayTime" placeholder="time"></ion-datetime>
          </ion-col>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label for="q3">Time</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime displayFormat="hh:mm A" [(ngModel)]="TakeAwayTime" id="q3"></ion-datetime>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-radio-group>
      </ion-list>
</ion-app>
````

Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-uxrac1